# SSRS displaying image from database

Tags: reporting-services

I am trying to display image from database in my SSRS report.  The report has two datasets.
For all text boxes etc. I have added value expression as below:

```
=First(Fields!Branding4Tx.Value, "dsPrintOData_tblProdOrders")
```

But when I do this in the value field of image box, it return an error.

```
=Fields!ProdImage1.Value, "dsPrintOData_tblProdOrders"
```

If I just put `=Fields!ProdImage1.Value
it does not return error but does not display any image too.
Please advise.
Thanks`

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the value in the ProdImage1 field. If it is a VARBINARY(MAX) data type value, then we can select Database as the image Source. If it is a string of the image URL, then we should select External as the image Source.

The following blog about Rendering images from a database on SSRS reports is for your reference:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2978/rendering-images-from-a-database-on-ssrs-reports/