# How to display image using Image control inside a table dynamically?

Tags: reporting-services

I have the below

[image]

and I would like to display the images using Image control inside a table dynamically. This is what I have tried

[image]

but the result is

[image]

so there are two things to be done

a) As can be figured out that I have chosen Mime Type as "images/png" (first image in png). It can be a mix of images/jpge or /png also

b) Why the images are not displaying ? where I am going wrong ?

The table schema is presented below

```
create table tblImageTest(Id int, EmployeeName varchar(100), CancellationImage varchar(100))
insert into tblImageTest values(1, 'emp1','1.PNG')
insert into tblImageTest values(2, 'emp2','2.jpg')
insert into tblImageTest values(3, 'emp3','3.jpg')
insert into tblImageTest values(4, 'emp4','4.jpg')
```

and the Stored Procedure also

```
alter procedure usp_imagetest
as
begin

select *,CancellationImagePath = 'F:\imagefolder\' + CancellationImage 
from tblImageTest

end
```

**N.B.~** *We can't store the images in the database as Blob. That's the limitation .Only image path is available.*

**Edit**

This is the result after I deployed in browser

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this out locally.

*b) Why the images are not displaying ? where I am going wrong ?*

I think you don't have to select Database as Image source rather External reason.

Edit: You will have to add file:// in front of your Image path.

[image]

[image]

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/713f3dcd-d153-40a7-8593-154bef95ed5a/adding-image-from-external-path-in-ssrs?forum=sqldatawarehousing

Reason:

It depends on the value in the Image field. If it is a VARBINARY(MAX) data type value, then we can select Database as the image Source. If it is a string of the image URL, then we should select External as the image Source.

[SSRS displaying image from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27701631/ssrs-displaying-image-from-database)

Comment: But it's not an image URL. Only a physical path of F:\ imagefolder\....    I have just now tried by changing to External but with no luck. Even I have tried changing the path as File: F:\imagefolder\1.jpg   but still no images is displayed